# Tracing Kernel mode (privileged) instructions in Qemu

Tags: c, callback, linux-kernel, arm, qemu

I am trying to write a Qemu TCG plugin to recognize if an instruction is executed in user mode or in kernel mode for a basic program.
I understand that a full system emulation is needed for the same. I wrote a TCG plugin, registering two Qemu callbacks `qemu_plugin_register_vcpu_syscall_cb` and `qemu_plugin_register_vcpu_syscall_ret_cb`. I am using the target `arm-softmmu` for full system emulation (and then the corresponding `qemu-system-arm`). I can see that there are `svc` calls in the user mode but I do not get any kernel-mode instructions. Any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: I thought `qemu-arm-softmmu` is user-mode emulation? `qemu-system-arm` is probably what you want? The user-mode emulation forwards syscalls to the host. So you won't be able to trace kernel instructions.

Comment: @ntrung03 I have expanded the question. The target is `arm-softmmu`.

Comment: Ummm, I have never seen this plugins being calls for system mode emulation... Plugins is a feature of user mode emulation.

Comment: For one such plugin, check the plugin `/contrib/plugins/hwprofile.c`. From the [documentation](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devel/tcg-plugins.html#example-plugins)

`The hwprofile tool can only be used with system emulation and allows the user to see what hardware is accessed how often`

Comment: Yeah, but I can only find the callback being made in bsd-user stuff. At least for qemu_plugin_vcpu_syscall